# Should be object A changeable from object B which inherits its prototype via Object.create?

Tags: javascript

Lets have two objects A and B:

```
var A = function() {}
var B = function() {}
```

Now lets say that B "inherits" prototype from A via Object.create:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Here comes the question, **Is it correct behavior that we can change A from B?**
For example via:

```
B.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.flower = "rose";
alert(A.flower); // rose
```

PS: I'm asking just because I'm interested about anything in javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct behavior"? If you're asking if it can be done, then obviously the answer is yes and you probably know that already.

Comment: Should be descendant able to influence its parent? I don't know. I guess it should be clear from there: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5 but it is not for me, so I ask...